# Does using shared libraries lead to having a single instance of global variables?

Tags: c, global-variables, shared-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Suppose we have a program (executable) `prog` that links to `libA` and `libB`. Both `libA` and `libB` in turn link to `libX`, which contains a global variables.

Will the global variable have a single instance, or two different instances within the `prog` process in the following cases?

1. `prog` is linking to `libA` and `libB` is dynamically, but both of those link to `libX` statically. (I assume two instances?)
2. `prog` is linking to `libA` and `libB` is dynamically, and both of those link to `libX` dynamically. (I assume one instance?)
3. `prog` is linking to `libA` and `libB` is statically, and both of those link to `libX` statically. (I assume one instance again?)

Additionally:

- Does it make a difference if the global was declared `static` (local to the translation unit)? In my use case, it is.
- Does the answer to these questions differ between operating systems? (macOS, Linux, Windows)
- Can you recommend some reading which explains the fundamentals that I need to be able to answer similar questions myself?

Comment: Why not check it?

Comment: @KamilCuk I am looking to get a deeper understanding of the topic. Checking this on a single platform won't give me that.

Comment: The "link to ... statically" is strange to me. You can't "link statically" with something. A static library is collection of object files, you can't "link with it". You can compile it into executable or into share library. Linking statically basically means compiling.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't really want to nitpick about terminology. Do you need clarifications to the question? If yes, I can try to improve it.

Comment: Yes. By "linking statically" you mean compilation?

Comment: @KamilCuk  Static linking is *not* compilation. I can compile an object library on one computer and *link* it to code that I compile on another computer. The library may even be compiled in a language for which the second computer doesn't have a compiler. Static and dynamic linking are two separate concepts (the former at build time, the latter at run time).

Comment: "link it to code that I __compile__" - I see compile here. Yes - this is my problem, "linking with shared" is runtime, "linking statically" is build time.

Comment: I think Adrian answered this. If you want to put it into practical terms, libX can be a static archive (.a file) or a shared object (.so file). Then when you create `liba.so` you either pass `libx.a` to the linker or `-la` (if you have `libx.so`).

Comment: As long as you dont put a variable in a shared segment, the variables will be process specific. So each instance will have a "local" global copy of the variable.

Comment: @Devolus: This question is not about multiple processes.

Comment: You say: *Does it make a difference if the global was declared static (local to the translation unit)?* This is confusing: if it's *local*, then it ain't *global*.

Comment: If I understand case 3 correctly, it does not exist. A static library is just a collection of object files; it can't link against a library itself.

Comment: @Pedro By the 3rd case I meant: compile libA, libB and libX into a static archive, then link all of them together with prog's code to create a single executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> prog is linking to libA and libB is dynamically, but both of those link to libX statically. (I assume two instances?)

In this case, the answer depends on which symbols are *exported* from `libA.so` and `libB.so`.

If the variable (let's call it `glob`) has static linkage, then it will not be exported and you will have two separate instances.

Likewise, if the variable doesn't have static linkage, but `libX` is compiled with e.g. `-fvisibility-hidden`, or if either `libA.so` or `libB.so` is linked with a linker script which prevents the `glob` from being exported, you will have two separate instances.

However, if the variable has global linkage and its visibility is not restricted via one of the above mechanisms, then (by default) it will be exported from both `libA.so` and `libB.so`, and in that case all references to that variable will bind to whichever library is loaded first.

**Update:**

> will there be two instances of that variable in memory, but just the first one is accessible, or the linker will not reserve any space at all for the second variable?

There will be two instances in memory.

When the linker builds `libA.so`, or `libB.so`, it *has no idea* what other libraries exist, and so it must reserve space in the readable and writable segment (the segment into which `.data` and `.bss` sections usually go) of the corresponding library.

At runtime, the loader `mmap`s the *entire* segment, and thus has no chance of *not* reserving memory space for the variable in each library.

But when the code *references* the variable at runtime, the loader will resolve all such references to the first symbol it encounters.

Note: above is the *default* behavior on ELF systems. Windows DLLs behave differently, and linking libraries with `-Bsymbolic` may change the outcome of symbol resolution as well.

> prog is linking to libA and libB is dynamically, and both of those link to libX dynamically. (I assume one instance?)

Correct.

> prog is linking to libA and libB is statically, and both of those link to libX statically. (I assume one instance again?)

This is an impossible scenario: you can't link `libA.a` against `libX.a`.

But when linking `prog` against `libA.a`, `libB.a` and `libX.a`, yes: you will end up with one instance of `glob`.

Comment: I'm curious `it will be exported from both libA.so and libB.so, and in that case all references to that variable will bind to whichever library is loaded first` in such case: will there be two instances of that variable in memory, but just the first one is accessible, or the linker will not reserve any space at all for the second variable?

Answer (score -1):

C does not have a global namespace. It has file scope (and others) and external linkage (and internal and none). In the situations described, using normal link methods, a static object defined in `libX` will have one instance in the program, regardless of whether its linkage is internal (declared with `static`) or external (without).

Comment: Is this the case even when libA and libB (both being shared libraries) were linked statically to libX? I would have expected this to create two separate global variable instances, one in libA and one in libB.

Comment: @Szabolcs: If you link libX to libA, making new combined object modules (either standalone or in a new library file) and remove the external symbols of libX and do the same with libX to libB, then link these two new object modules or libraries to one executable, you could produce an executable with two copies of libX and its internal data. So it can be possible with special link techniques. (If you do not remove the external symbols in at least one of those, the link to one executable should fail due to multiple definitions.)